# Pass a tap from UIScrollView to its parent view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has a UIScrollView in it that covers the entire cell.  I want to be able to use the scroll view to scroll a label in the cell (which is working) but the scroll view seems to be 'stealing' the cell's tap event.  So I was wondering:

How do you pass a touch event from a UIScrollView to its parent UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

In the UISCrollViewController, have you tried passing the touchesEnded on to super, assuming a scroll is not in progress?

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)aTouches withEvent:(UIEvent *)anEvent
{
    if(![self isDragging])
    {
    [super touchesEnded:aTouches withEvent:anEvent];
    }
}
```